# How to select specific items from Laravel request object without converting to Array

Tags: laravel, request

i want to select specific item or items from laravel Request Object and so again send that to other method without convert to Arrat

for example:

my request items:

```
[
  "product_id", 
  "item1", 
  "item2", 
  "user" => [
       "id",
       "name",
       "family" 
  ]
]
```

i have a method with type hint like:

```
getProduct(Request $request){
  // only need to Product items

  // step tow 
// it i use $requedt->only("user") $reuest convert to Array!
  $this->userOfProduct($request)
}
```

and I have another method like get

```
userOfProduct(Request $reuest){
/// on this step font neet do procuct items on my request!

 user_id = $request["id"];
 user_name = $request["name"];
 user_family = $request["family"];
}
```

what is a problem:

I cant use $request->only("user") becuse this convert $request model to array!

why I do this?

i use userOfProduct method from another place in application so I should be getting only $request["id"] from Request object and if I use for example like this $request["user"]->id or another way, this method don't work when i user another place of my app because somewhere

so now: HOW can is select user items from my request model and again send request object to my userOfProduct method without convert to Array

Comment: try this.. `$user = (object) $request->user;`

Answer (score 0):

`$request->input('user')` will give you user and you can do `$request->input('user')['name']` to get user's name.